# Cocoa View does not apply changed font for label

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, view, label

I'm trying to change the font of a lable in a UIView
for my iPhone App.

The change of the 'Font' in the Attribute Inspector does not have any effect
on the font.

Any idea?

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: No code, just using the Interface Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might explain it.

http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/iphone_fonts